# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

Relearning C++ for the sake of using OpenCL. I have created a Helper Class called CheckDevice which has a bunch of boiler plate code for getting device stats.

CheckDevice.h

```
    class Utils
    {
    public:
        Utils(){};
        ~Utils(){};


        template<class T>
        static bool IsNull(T Object, char* name);

    private:

    };
```

CheckDevice.cpp

```
    cl_command_queue Utils::CreateCommandQueue(cl_context context, cl_device_id *device)
    {
        cl_int err;
        cl_device_id *devices;
        cl_command_queue queue  = NULL;
        size_t deviceBufferSize = -1;
        cl_kernel kernel = 0;


        Utils::IsNull<cl_command_queue>(queue, "Utils::CreateCommandQueue::queue");



        return queue;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
    void main()
    {

        cl_kernel kernel            = 0;


        Utils::IsNull<cl_kernel>(kernel, "clCreateKernel");

    }
```

The question is when calling the function Utils::IsNull from within CheckDevice.cpp it works fine but when calling from main.cpp than I get the following in Visual Studios 2012

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Utils::IsNull(struct _cl_kernel *,char *)" (??$IsNull@PAU_cl_kernel@@@Utils@@SA_NPAU_cl_kernel@@PAD@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Users\Suri\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Any Help would be apperciated

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`. Whatever book or tutorial you're using should not have told you that `void main()` is correct, and your compiler should have warned you about it. Get a better book, and enable warnings in your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the implementation of the `IsNull` template, but probably it is in `CheckDevice.cpp`. It should be placed in `CheckDevice.h` instead, the compiler needs to see it's definition to be able to instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks So much it worked. Your right I left the implementation of IsNull out of the question by accident. Why is this the case? I have other functions that have no issue begin called from CheckDevice.cpp. Has it something to do with the template?

Answer (score -2):

- There is a calling convention problem on the main.cpp. When you are trying to make a function call on the main, you need first to create an instance of that class object, before you make a function call. You are missing that on your main.
- So basically you need to create an instance of Utils and make a reference to it.
- cl_kernel kernel = 0;
- Utils *ut = new Utils();
- ut->IsNull"<"cl_kernel">"(kernel, "clCreateKernel");

Comment: But it's a static function..

Comment: Also why are you passing a string as a template type?

Comment: You can still call a static function on the main by using a pointer to class instance. It works just fine.

Comment: Right, but it's not needed and wasn't the issue.